# How to convert `BlockNumber` to `u64`?

Tags: frame

For example, if a have a variable of type `<T as frame_system::Config>::BlockNumber` how could I convert it into a `u64`, simply putting `u64::from` doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```rust
use sp_runtime::traits::SaturatedConversion;


fn f(block_number: BlockNumber) {
    block_number.saturated_into::<u64>();
}
```

Comment: Depending on what is the intended behaviour when the block number doesn't fit into 64 bits, using [CheckedConversion](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_runtime/traits/trait.CheckedConversion.html) might be an option as well.